# Android: ListView wont scroll when drawer is added

Tags: android, listview, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

I try to add a custom `Navigation Drawer` to an `Activity` with a `ListView`.
Before I added the `Navigation Drawer`, the `ListView` could be scrolled and you could select items, but when I added the drawer it doesn't do it anymore.
When I add the `ListView` above the `Navigation Drawer`, the `Navigation Drawer` works.
But when I put the `ListView` under it, the `Navigation Drawer` doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.theoryx.androidapp.Search">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/snackbarPosition">
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

//<include layout="@layout/content_my_library" />  //<----here   

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_my_library" /> //when I put this above it the drawer works but then the listview doesn't scroll and cant be selected.

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Content_my_library:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.theoryx.androidapp.MyLibrary"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my_library">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `DrawerLayout` the root element if you want to use navigation drawer.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        <!-- All the things. -->
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: That code is exactly the same as in the question and alone means nothing. Add more to demonstrate your idea.

Comment: basically the Drawer Layout has to be root element  that just snip i don't know how he wants to structure layout

Comment: ***I*** get what you mean. But I'm not asking the question. Please be more verbose next time.

Comment: Thanks , will be more specific next time